# Slider using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a numeric slide as below; without using HTML5 and jquery library

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Why the restriction on jquery? There is no native slider control, so it would be a case of writing one yourself or using one from another library.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Comment: one of our client ask to design it using pure JavaScript without using any jquery... that is the reason i was saying with out jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [dhtmlxSlider](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSlider/index.shtml) ? Its a slide bar which uses simple Javascript, and HTML 4.01 strict.

I believe its compatible with most browsers, and free to download from this link here: [Download link for dhtmlxSlider](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSlider/index.shtml)

Here is an example of the code to use dhtmlxSlider:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var slider1;
function doLoadLiveDemo(){
slider1=new dhtmlxSlider(
   "sliderBox1",
   260,
   "dhx_skyblue");

slider1.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/");
slider1.setStep(50);
slider1.attachEvent(
"onChange",
function(nv){document.getElementById("qual").value=nv;});
slider1.init(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI's Range Slider:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Check out the demo page here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/range.html

Comment: Didn't you notice they don't want to use jquery?

Comment: without using jquery shall we do it

Comment: Ah! Sorry. Missed that point. But yea, will check and update the answer. Sorry guys! Saw the without `HTML5` part.

Comment: I saw this: http://css3wizardry.com/2010/09/14/range-slider-with-css-and-javascript/ BUt it uses Prototype.